# Can anyone help me detect the dimensions inconsistency that gives segmentation error?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

this is driving me crazy... I am basically doing this code, being `a[m].size()=48`, and `transform_dimension.size()=6`. It is giving me the annoying segmentation fault, i have gone through all dimensions muliple times and cannot spot the mistake, can someone help? It is c++

```
void transform (vector<vector<int>> a, int m)
{
  vector<bitset<8> > transform_dimension;
  for (int i=0; i<a[m].size(); i+=8)
  {
    for (int j=0; j<8; j++)
    {
      bitset<8> b;
      b[7-j]=a[m][i+j];
      transform_dimension[i/8]=b;
    }
  }
  for (int i=0; i<transform_dimension.size(); i++)
    cout<<transform_dimension[i]<<endl;

}
```

Comment: give the values you pass as arguments on the call that causes the segfault. In other words please create a [MRE]

Answer (score 5):

This is a vector of size zero.

```
vector<bitset<8> > transform_dimension;
```

This next line accesses a vector of size zero. Doesn't matter what the value of `i` is, a vector of size zero has no elements and you cannot legally use `[]` on it.

```
transform_dimension[i/8]=b;
```

You seem to have the common but completely incorrect belief that vectors adjust their sizes when you assign to a given index.

Based on your description it seems that if you change

```
vector<bitset<8> > transform_dimension;
```

to

```
vector<bitset<8> > transform_dimension(a[m].size()/8);
```

the code will work (or at least have one less bug). With that code you are creating the vector at the required size.